# Call AWS Step Functions from .Net

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I am calling a step function from a Lambda function, in a loop. However I am getting a ExecutionAlreadyExistsException. What am I doing wrong here?

```
[Fact]
    public async void ActualSchedulingEngineStepFunctionCallTest()
    {
      var amazonStepFunctionsConfig = new AmazonStepFunctionsConfig { RegionEndpoint = RegionEndpoint.USWest2 };
      using (var amazonStepFunctionsClient = new AmazonStepFunctionsClient(awsAccessKeyId, awsSecretAccessKey, amazonStepFunctionsConfig))
      {
        var input = new Input
        {
          ID = "24232323232323232",
          Status = 1,
          Type = "Interim"
        };
        var jsonData1 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(input);
        var startExecutionRequest = new StartExecutionRequest
        {
          Input = jsonData1,
          Name = "SchedulingEngine",
          StateMachineArn = "arn:aws:states:us-west-2:<SomeNumber>:stateMachine:SchedulingEngine"
        };
        var taskStartExecutionResponse = await amazonStepFunctionsClient.StartExecutionAsync(startExecutionRequest);
        Assert.Equal(HttpStatusCode.OK, taskStartExecutionResponse.HttpStatusCode);
      }
    }
```

**Stack trace:**

```
Amazon.StepFunctions.Model.ExecutionAlreadyExistsException : Execution Already Exists: 'arn:aws:states:us-west-2:<SomeNumber>:execution:SchedulingEngine:SchedulingEngine'
---- Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException : Exception of type 'Amazon.Runtime.Internal.HttpErrorResponseException' was thrown.
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/stepfunctions/model/ExecutionAlreadyExistsException.html

Comment: You already have execution with name "SchedulingEngine". That's why you are getting this error. You need to provide different name or delete the existing execution with name "SchedulingEngine" before creating a new one with the name.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. Read my other comment to understand issue and possible solution to it.

Comment: @chetan: Thanks for your input. Sometimes it helps to talk to the community when you have a brain freeze.

Answer (score 4):

Change the Name

`Name = "SchedulingEngine" <----- It should be unique for each execution`

Answer (score 0):

remove the "name" parameter , it's not required if you need to execute state machine frequently